# CakePHP ignorando meu Model

Tags: cakephp

Porque o cake está ignorando meu Model? Não entendo.
Tenho vários outros Models funcionando perfeitamente, mas esse não está dando certo. Está sendo ignorado.

Nome do model: **TiposObservacao.php**

Conteúdo do model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class TiposObservacao extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'tipos_observacoes';
    public $primaryKey = 'tipo_observacao_id';

   public $hasMany = array(
     "Observacao" => array(
              'className' => 'Atendimento.Observacao',
              'foreignKey' => 'tipo_observacao_id',
            )
   );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu controller associado à essa model se chama "TiposObservacaos", obedecendo a convenção de nomes estabelecida, então o Cake deve reconhecer sem problema.

Se a model for utilizada em qualquer outro controller, utilize o atributo $uses:

```
class QualquerController extends AppController
{
     public $uses = array('TiposObservacao');
}
```

Dessa maneira, o Cake vai instanciar a model pra você na variável $TiposObservacao

```
$this->TiposObservacao->find();
```

Comment: Ontem, depois de tanto quebrar a cabeça, descobri que eu estava pecando num detalhe besta: no loadModel, esqueci de colocar também o nome do Plugin antes do nome do Model. De qualquer forma, obrigado.

Comment: Obs: O loadModel é utilizado "on the fly", para apenas setar o model correto use o `$uses`, como sugerido.